# Jenkins: Multiple tasks or build dependent project after first (even if first fails)

Tags: jenkins

I have some reports that I would like to push up to Github after my main project target builds.

These reports should be pushed up whether the first project succeeds or not. Can Jenkins do either of the following:

- Specify multiple tasks (like Bamboo).
- Build another project after the first, even if the first fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reading your comment on the other Answers I propose this solution for you Jasper**

Keep you existing project that builds and generates your reports and create a new project that you might call "report uploader" which only uploads your reports to your git.

1) Main Project Build

- this will build you system, run it and test it (resulting in some reports, let's call them  REPORT.o)
- this project might or might not fail
- REPORT.o should be archived as artifacts then the build is finished
- the job should always trigger the "report uploader" job - **Use the** [parameterized build trigger plugging](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)
- make sure this job has the checkbox wait for downstream jobs (else a new job might be started and overwrite the report files)

2) Report uploader Build

- this will project will take arguments from the upstream job to find the artifacts
- fetch them and upload them to whatever server you like to have

The same concept is loosely described on [jenkins wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Splitting+a+big+job+into+smaller+jobs)

hope this fits your need

Comment: Good info, I'll give it a try. I didn't realize jobs could share artifacts. . . meantime, I've solved it by adding adding a target called 'no-fail' and running the whole thing again: ant no-fail build-publish  . . not very efficient, i'll have to come back and fix as per your advice. . . (at least its working for now though)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

With Git publisher you can push to a branch and choose whether or not to only do so when the build succeeds.

There is also a post-build action where you can build other projects and an option to do so even if the build fails.

Comment: NB: Actually this is not quite what I want. . I can trigger a new build, but that requires a new checkout, so the test results that I want to publish won't be there. . . I'll have to modify my script a to run tests again on the new checkout, but not fail the build, and then proceed to other docs, finally running my publish target.